# What makes a Moleskine notebook so good and when should someone invest in them?

Tags: tools, sketching

What makes [Moleskine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moleskine) so frequently cited as the go-to sketchbook for artists.

StackExchange offered us Moleskine notebooks (though I still never got mine!). There's countless [pages on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=moleskine%20drawings&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) dedicated to Moleskine drawings.

What qualities make the Moleskine the most highly sought after sketchbook and at what point should a person start purchasing them? For example, should a day 1 illustrator invest in them? If you're only sketching with pencil will you see the benefits or not until you start exploring inks and colors?

Comment: I personally think this is a case of style and status over utility. I have a moleskin, and haven't found it to be that special, except making me feel like a hipster. I've found better (and cheaper) notebooks out there.

Comment: @Scribblemacher please leave that as an answer if that's your take so others can upvote/downvote/comment and I can potentially accept it if it appears to be the consensus answer.

Comment: The one advantage to Moleskine is that if you like them, you can be reasonably sure of being able to buy the same notebook again later - and getting pretty much the same product. Other recognizable brands have the same property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion Moleskine are more looks and brand than quality. Not that I think they are bad, I personally like them but I've had better quality as well.

I don't think this is necessarily a bad thing though, as 'pretty things' help me get inspired. I would grab my beloved, nice looking notebook much quicker than an old drab. Next to this I also like that where I live they are quite widely available, even most bookstores sell them.

I don't think the paper feels any better than the average *decent* notebook when I'm sketching with pencils. I don't have much experience with markers or paint though.

If you don't care about looks or brands however, feel free to buy anything else.

Nobody *needs* a Moleskine.

Comment: Style and ubiquity, the iPhone of the notebook world.